# Spring boot parent (2.3.0.RELEASE) exception handling method not called when attributes null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest controller that has a requestObject that contains 3 attributes and they are mandatory. Basically I  have the class below which contains method constraintViolationException to deal with  @NotBlank exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    // @Validate For Validating Path Variables and Request Parameters
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  //TODO - to provide custom error message
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }

}
```

My Controller is shown below:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {



    @PostMapping(value = "/processMyPayment")
    public  ResponseEntity<?> processMyPayment(@Valid MyRequest myRequest ) {

        MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(myTResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
...
```

When I add the class MyExceptionHandler and send null attributes it my rest controller it should call the  constraintViolationException since the values are null but it is not the case  and I get the following result:
[image]

. However when I remove the **extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** I get the whole stacktrace:

```
"timestamp": "2020-06-05T13:01:47.715+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"trace": "org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors\nField error in object 'myRequest' on field 'amount': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.myRequest.amount,NotBlank.amount,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myRequest.amount,amount]; arguments []; default message [amount]]; default message [Amount name mandatory]\nField error in object 'myRequest' on field 'accountId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.myRequest.accountId,NotBlank.accountId,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myRequest.accountId,accountId]; arguments []; default message [accountId]]; default message [Account id is mandatory]\nField error in object 'myRequest' on field 'accountName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.myRequest.accountName,NotBlank.accountName,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myRequest.accountName,accountName]; arguments []; default message [accountName]]; default message [Account name mandatory]\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n",
"message": "Validation failed for object='myRequest'. Error count: 3",
"errors":[
{"codes":["NotBlank.myRequest.amount", "NotBlank.amount", "NotBlank.java.lang.String", "NotBlank" ],…},
{"codes":["NotBlank.myRequest.accountId", "NotBlank.accountId", "NotBlank.java.lang.String", "NotBlank" ],…},
{"codes":["NotBlank.myRequest.accountName", "NotBlank.accountName", "NotBlank.java.lang.String", "NotBlank" ],…}
],
"path": "/processMyPayment"
}
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that instead of providing the stack-trace I just want to add the fields that are null with an error message that  those fields cannot be null.

Any idea how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach the code of controller?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I have added the controller class

Comment: Hi no still not working

Comment: Check your response body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
     * Handles javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException. Thrown when @Validated fails.
     *
     * @param ex the ConstraintViolationException
     * @return error
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(
            javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        // list of violations
        // ex.getConstraintViolations();

        // return custom error
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
```

You should override the method `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()` of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, like this:

```
/**
     * Handle @see MethodArgumentNotValidException. Triggered when an object fails validation.
     *
     * @param ex      the @see MethodArgumentNotValidException that is thrown when validation fails
     * @param headers   HttpHeaders @see HttpHeaders
     * @param status    HttpStatus  @see HttpStatus
     * @param request   WebRequest @see WebRequest
     * @return ResponseEntity<Object>
     */
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {

            // get Binding Result
            Object bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
            // get specific field errors
            Object fieldErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
            // get error counts
            int errorCount = ex.getBindingResult().getErrorCount();

            // return, you can create custom responses based on fieldErrors and errorCounts as well and send that in the body below.
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(fieldErrors);
    }
```

When you override this function as above, you will find that this method gets called whenever any `@Valid` validation fails. You can change return type.

Let me know after you test it. You may also check an open source tested project for custom exception handler and responses ->
https://github.com/AccessGateLabs/response-builder/

Link for specific class that handles custom exceptions -> https://github.com/AccessGateLabs/response-builder/blob/master/src/main/java/com/accessgatelabs/oss/builder/exceptions/RestExceptionHandler.java

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but the response is not defined in the method parameter

Comment: Have made changes in the above code for your reference, Please look at it, and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Can you specifically share what's not working and also if possible, share your screenshot too again. Please once refer to above both GitHub Links (will be extremely helpful for you).

Comment: Have added a new code snippet in above answer. Please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are handling the wrong exception. `ConstraintViolationException` is meant for entity/domain object validation. Spring throws a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` in the web layer if using `@Valid` on controller's method argument. You could modify your exception handler as such:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<CustomErrorResponse> handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    // You could extract default error messages from the exception
    val errors = getErrors(e)
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(CustomErrorResponse.of(errors)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out the issue in case of someone else come across this, i am posting it.Basically I had to override the following method:

```
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
//add custom implementation here
            return this.handleExceptionInternal(ex, (Object)null, headers, status, request);
    }
```